# How to know your PC's RAM model on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory, dell-latitude

I've got a DELL Latitude E5470 and it's got an 8GB RAM. I saw there is an empty slot so I can put another one but I'm not sure which one to choose: [this one](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-memory-upgrade-8gb-2rx8-ddr4-sodimm-2133mhz/apd/a8547953/memory) or [this one](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-memory-upgrade-8gb-1rx8-ddr4-sodimm-2400mhz/apd/a9210967/memory#polaris-pd)...

I didn't see any sticker on my current RAM board, so I was wondering if there is a way to check the model or at least the clock speed of my RAM on Windows 10.

Comment: https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: Thank you the memory tab doesn't give it all the information I need, coz both are DDR4 and in the software it says DRAM Frequency:  1064MHz, so I looked at the SPD tab it says: DDR4-2132(1066MHz) 8GB from Micron technologies, so I looked in their website, but I can't find the model with the same part number, so I contact them...would you do something different? Thanks @wysiwyg !

Comment: http://www.softnology.biz/files.html Thaiphoon Burner reads all of the data straight from the DRAM modules.

Answer (score 3):

[From you support page](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/latitude-e5470-laptop/manuals) Owners manual

Memory capacity:

4 GB, 8 GB, and 16 GB

Memory type

DDR4 SDRAM

Speed
2133 MHz

Minimum memory
4 GB

Maximum memory
16 GB

Comment: but I think if I want to add it, it has to be exactly the same model as the one I already have, hasn't it?

Comment: Define "model", you can mix brands and speeds, but bios will clock all memory modules to match the slowest one installed.

Comment: I mean, same manufacturer, same specs? so if I add a different manufacturer and any of the specs is different won't work? Let's say the clock is different, it just won't work, right?

Comment: It should work as I stated before "you can mix brands and speeds, but bios will clock all memory modules to match the slowest one installed."

Answer (score 1):

> I've got a DELL Latitude E5470 but I'm not sure which one to choose

[image]

Which means the Dell Memory Upgrade - 8GB - 2RX8 DDR4 SODIMM 2133MH is compatible with your system.  However, Dell Memory Upgrade - 8GB - 1RX8 DDR4 SODIMM 2400MHz, is also compatible with your system.  So it doesn’t matter which one you purchase.

Comment: but I think if I want to add it, it has to be exactly the same as the one I already have, hasn't it?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT it was a product page provided by the author.  The link isn’t required to answer this question I will just remove it.  I would appreciate be called by my actual handle.

Comment: I will just remove it.... I use short form from time to time so I cannot remember all requests as such but I'll try to remember that... Thanks!!